# Trying to use mysql connector inside a function

Tags: python, mysql, flask, scope, mysql-connector

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField,IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask import Flask,render_template
import os
import requests
import mysql.connector
import sys
import json
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="tester",
    password="test@123",
    database="flaskapp"
    )
cur=mydb.cursor()
def insert_steamid(s):
    
    api_key=""
    res=requests.get("https://api.brawlhalla.com/search?steamid="+str(s)+"&api_key="+api_key);
    data=json.loads(res.text)
    brawl_id=str(data['brawlhalla_id'])
    res2=requests.get("https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/"+brawl_id+"/ranked?api_key="+api_key)
    data2=json.loads(res2.text)
    rank=data2['global_rank']
    # if(rank==0):
    #     return("no competitive stats available")
    temp=(rank,data2['name'],data2['brawlhalla_id'],data2['region'],data2['legends'][0]['legend_id'])
    sql = "insert into test_table  values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    try:
        cur.execute(sql,temp)
        mydb.commit()
        return("data added")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        return(err)



class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)



class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = IntegerField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')


main_query="select players_1v1.rankp , players_1v1.name , players_1v1.region , legends.legend_name_key  from players_1v1,legends where players_1v1.best_legend = legends.legend_id ;"
cur.execute(main_query)
data=cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
mydb.close()




@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def example(): 
    print("ss")
    # cursor.execute("select * from legends") 
    # data = cursor.fetchall() 
    return render_template("index.html", test=data) 

@app.route('/ent',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    steam_id=int(0)
    form = LoginForm()
    msg=str('')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        msg=insert_steamid(form.username.data)
        print(msg)
        # print('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
        #     form.username.data, "u"))
    else:
        print("no")
    return render_template('form.html', title='Sign In', form=form, message=msg)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my program, what I am trying to do is run some SQL queries from a function, but this doesn't seem to work well. I have to redefine `mydb` and `cur` in the function again to get it working. What am I doing wrong?
**EDIT: I closed the cursor before the cursor was called by the `insert_steamid` function after executing `main_query`. It was a silly mistake on my part**

Comment: I do not see a (python) function...

Comment: "doesn't seem to work well" is not an accurate description of your problem. At the very least you should add the code for `insert_steamid`, surely there has to be something more ? And also, what the cursor actually does. The cursor may have to be moved inside the function too, depending on what you are trying to achieve. This code is incomplete for the purpose of discussion because it does not fully illustrate the "problem".

Comment: @Luuk I have edited the function and added the whole thing,

Comment: You don't need `global cur`.  You need `cur = mydb.cursor()`.

Comment: @TimRoberts nope, it does not work it gives MySQL Connection not available.. I added mydb before the function and declared cur inside the function.

Comment: Are you running a MySQL server on your local computer?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes

Comment: did you test the return value for `insert_steamid()`? And are you sure that it is not `no competitive stats available` ?

Comment: @Luuk yes I did, it shows cursor not connected

Comment: Why do I see in your code   `cur.close()
mydb.close()` ?

Comment: @Luuk ohh good god, that was the problem, I didn't notice it until now, much thanks

Comment: Seeing that you use Flask, I would suggest that you use SQL Alchemy, note that there is an implementation for Flask: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/. Even if you don't want to use the abstraction of the ORM you can still make raw queries but at least DB management would be slightly improved.

Comment: @Anonymous oh ok, , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to debug your code.

I stripped down some of it, and did a test with:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="test",
password="test",
database="test"
)
cur=mydb.cursor()
def insert_steamid(s):
        sql = "SELECT count(*) as i FROM numm"
        print("test")
        try:
            cur.execute(sql)
            for (i) in cur:
                print(s,i)
            mydb.commit()
            return("data added")
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            return(err)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="test",
password="test",
database="test"
)
cur=mydb.cursor()
print(insert_steamid("abc"))
```

The results are:

```
test
abc (10,) 
data added
```

Which are correct, because there are 10 records in my `numm` table.

Maybe I should vote for "close because not reproduceable"?

Comment: I updated the question and added the full code fo my app, I am developing this in flask,I tried it out your snippet, it seems to work ok, i don't know why i get cursor not connected in my case

Comment: OK, I am pretty new to python, so I will not dive into flask.... 